# Using variable inside array.push() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a for loop in my jquery script

```
var images[];
for(i=0;i<$('#imageHolder div').length;i++)
{
    images.push($('#imageHolder div:eq( i )').attr('alt'));
    console.log($('#imageHolder div:eq(i )').attr('alt'));
}
```

I am not able to add the elements to the array and the console.log says undefined in the console.
What is my possible error and how that can be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has useful method for this task, called [`$.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var images = $('#imageHolder div').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('alt');
}).get();
```

Will produce an array of images alt attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
images.push($('#imageHolder div:eq(' + i + ')').attr('alt')); 
                 you need to concat i ^^^^
```

By the way, don't select your element every time in the `for`

```
var divs = $('#imageHolder div');
for(i=0; i < divs.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a variable so need to use concatenation

```
$('#imageHolder div:eq('+  i + ')').attr('alt')
```

---

A more efficient way is to use .map(), in your case you are evaluating the selector many times which is not a optimal way

```
var images = $('#imageHolder div').map(function () {
    return $(this).attr('alt')
}).get()
```